# One-to-many relation in ASP.NET MVC4 and CodeFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having some problems with relationship over ASP.NET MVC4 and the CodeFirst, also with returning values with these tables which are related with foreign key.

First of all, let's see if I'm doing it correctly.

Here's a example of my code:

#### Person Class

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}
```

#### City Class

```
public class City {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, with this, the database created a nice looking relationship, and it seens to work very well. I have after this code, tables like this:

Person
--Id (PK)
--Name
--Surname
--City_Id  (FK)

City
--Id (PK)
--Name

I've populated this with a seed, here's a example:

```
context.Person.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name,
    new Person { Name = "Me", City = new City { Name = "Ludlow" } }
);
```

And when I need to retrieve the information to a view, like this...

**MyDataBase.cs**

```
public class LeilaoDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
MyDataBase _db = new MyDataBase();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = _db.Persons.ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
```

**Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<testingproject.Models.Person>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial( "_Person", item );
}
```

**_Person.cshtml**

```
@model testingproject.Models.Person

<div>
    <h3>@Model.Name</h3>
    @Model.City.Name
</div>
```

I receive a null exception...

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

So, what's wrong?

## Solution:

I found the solution,

```
MyDataBase _db = new MyDataBase();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _db.Persons.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

This code retrieves only the Persons, maybe to not overload when it's not necessary to do relationships. You need to specify when need to do these relationships with a `Include()` method.

After this, is simple:

```
MyDataBase _db = new MyDataBase();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _db.Persons.Include("City");

    return View(model);
}
```

I feel strange passing a string to this method, but it's ok. I now can return my values with `@Model.City.Name` if I really need.

I found the solution in this website [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232)

Comment: This is because you are using `Model` explicitly. If the @model did not receive any data then `Model` would be `null`. It is better to use helpers like `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)`. This takes care of the `null` case.

Comment: Are you passing a model to your view?

Comment: I passing a model to the view like this: `public ActionResult Index() { var model = _db.Persons.ToList(); return View(model) }` which in this case I have a `MyDataBase _db = new MyDataBase();` and I have a context which is `MyDataBase.cs` and inside this .cs, I have this: `public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }`, `public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }`

Comment: Sorry, I have other file which is: `@model IEnumerable<testingproject.Models.Leilao>` and below this `@foreach (var item in Model) { @Html.Partial( "_Person", item ); }`. And, If I remove the `@Model.City.Name`, the view return the name of the person.

Comment: It seems there might be some ambiguity because you're assigning to a property name `City` an instance of a class `City`...

Comment: You could try casting the property to a type like `((City)Model.City).Name`.

Comment: I found the solution, look at there. It's simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entitity framework does not do relationships unnecessary. If you want to include others table you need to call a method or make the properties as virtual to do a lazy relationship.

`public virtual City City { get; set; }`

this way, lazy mode is made.

`var model = _db.Persons.Include("City").ToList();`

and this way is the method to manualy include the relationship tables when necessary.

If you want to just call a person and not doing the join just call `_db.Persons.ToList();`